# Docker Oracle Instant Client

Tags: oracle, docker, makefile, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been trying for 4 days to:

- Deploy Oracle Instant Client with Docker. I can give you the Dockerfile but it is 96 lines
- To use Oracle Instant Client on my Linux Ubuntu latest.

In the end I arrive at the same two issues.

When installing OCI 8 with the command:

- Docker:

> RUN echo 'instantclient, / usr / local / instantclient' | pecl install
> oci8

- Ubuntu:

> echo "instantclient, / opt / oracle / instantclient_12_2" | sudo pecl
> install oci8

I get the error:

```
make: *** [Makefile: 194: oci8.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make 'failed
```

Could not find a solution.

Make is correctly installed in both cases:

> GNU Make 4.2.1 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Copyright (C) 1988-2016
> Free Software Foundation, Inc. GPLv3 + license: GNU GPL version 3 or
> later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free software: you
> are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the
> extent permitted by law.

Do you have an idea ? It blocks me for the rest of my work.

BR,

Nicolas.

EDIT :

I try this :

```
pear download pecl/oci8
tar xvzf oci8-3.0.0.tgz
phpize
./configure --with-oci8=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/
make
```

Same issue :

```
make: *** [Makefile:194: oci8.lo] Error 1
```

I'm going crazy...

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the instructions from Oracle's Github Repo for Docker you should be able to build your own instantclient.

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleInstantClient

Another option will be to just make use of an existing image from their container-registry.

```
docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/instantclient:latest
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Bjarte, 

I think my Oracle Instant Client is build local or in my docker container, i follow the instructions on :

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

With files.ZIP.

Now I have to install oci8 for PHP.

But 'Make' gives an error while installing this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
RUN echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient/lib' | pecl install oci8
```