# Docker and command docker-php

Tags: php, linux, docker, ubuntu

Following my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124167/linux-and-oracle-instant-client).

I managed to install oci8-2.2.0 via pecl.

Now I have a problem, I cannot launch the commands:

```
docker-php-ext- *
```

It always gives me an error:

```
/ bin / sh: 1: docker-php-ext-configure: not found
```

In my Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

COPY --from=library/docker:latest /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/bin/docker
COPY --from=docker/compose:latest /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

I install my necessary packages:

```
RUN apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    libapache2-mod-php \
    libldap2-dev \
    vim \
    curl \
    git \
    openssl \
    bash \
    mysql-client \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    make \
    libaio1 \
    wget \
    unzip \
    libapache2-mod-php7.4 \
    software-properties-common \
    systemtap-sdt-dev \
    build-essential \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    net-tools
```

I install the PHP dependencies:

```
RUN apt-add-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
     php7.4 \
     php7.4-fpm \
     php7.4-xml \
     php-common \
     php7.4-gd \
     php7.4-mbstring \
     php7.4-gd \
     php7.4-iconv \
     php7.4-pdo \
     php7.4-tokenizer \
     php7.4-mysql \
     php-ldap \
     php7.4-ldap \
     php7.4-fileinfo \
     php7.4-simplexml \
     php7.4-xmlwriter \
     php7.4-zip \
     php7.4-json \
     php-dev \
     php-pear
```

Finally, the commands are launched after installing Oracle Instant Client:

```
# Oracle instantclient
RUN export PHP_DTRACE=yes
ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /tmp/
ADD instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /tmp/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/
RUN mv /usr/local/instantclient_12_2 /usr/local/instantclient
RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so
RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1 /usr/local/instantclient/libocci.so

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient

RUN echo "instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient"| pecl install oci8-2.2.0

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_oci
RUN docker-php-ext-enable oci8-2.2.0
```

Any idea for Docker to find docker-php-ext- commands?

BR

Comment: check here)
https://github.com/krepysh-spec/lamp-docker-php-skeleton

Answer (score 1):

Commands `docker-php-ext- *` are helper scripts provided by [PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) images. But you are using `ubuntu:latest` image, which is doesn't contain them.

You can use scripts from php image for example [that](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-configure) one. But I think it is easier to use php docker images.

Comment: HOoooooooooooooo ok ! :)

Thank you so much !!

Comment: Another suggestion is to use Oracle Instant Client 19, which will connect to the same range of Oracle DB versions as the older 12c version you have.  Also it creates those symlinks for you.  Which ever version you use, I'd recommend using `ldconfig` instead of setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, see the Instant Client instructions on the download page.  Some Oracle Docker references are: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers and https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1